# How large can an Earth species be in 2016 without being discovered?

Tags: science-based, biology, environment, species

**Preface**
With all technology discovered prior to this question, on today's planet, there are still some things we have not observed - which may be used to justify introducing new life forms, right here at home, in a story.

---

**There are a LOT of unexplored places on Earth**

> - We've explored [less than five percent of the ocean](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/exploration.html)
> - We see evidence of [potentially new organisms but can't always locate them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/52-hertz_whale)
> - Plenty of undiscovered species [do exist](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/08/110824-earths-species-8-7-million-biology-planet-animals-science/)
> - Many rainforests have areas that are either uninhabited or that [modern scientists haven't been through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLErPqqCC54), ruling out discovery in
>     the "traditional" sense but allowing large creatures to go unnoticed
>     by science

---

**To be clear**

I am defining "undiscovered species" as:

- Somewhat unique. Cannot be a subspecies or a division of a well-known species into groups that are somewhat similar to each other.
- Unbeknownst to or denied by modern scientists. Can be seen by isolated or indigenous societies.
- Lacking observed evidence of existence to the point that any actual evidence found is explained by some other phenomena. Like if [the bloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloop) was an animal and we brushed it off as ice moving, or like if [this thing](http://natural-environment.com/blog/shell-oil-company-catches-alien-squid-on-camera/) wasn't actually a known animal, or if [this thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGk-yuYMAms) wasn't a sleeper shark.

---

**So the question is**

**Given the above information, how large can each of the following organisms plausibly be on Earth in 2016 while remaining undiscovered with current technology?**

- **Plant, fungus, or similar species**
- **Land animal**
- **Aquatic animal**

---

*I will not accept "*it will probably be..."* I would like calculations or references as opposed to speculation, please.

---

**Edit:** In response to all answers - I ask "how large can they be" not "what is a size they could be". I do apprciate your answers but every one seems to say "this is a large thing we've seen so an organism could be at least this large". What no answer **does say**, as the question asks, is "based on the ways we observe the world, an organism could be *at most* this large".

Comment: Since this is a question asking us to speculate on things that are plausible (i.e. they may or may not be true), the hard-science tag is inappropriate. You should go with science-based instead.

Comment: @kingledion - agreed, I wanted to submit an answer, but since it's tagged 'science-based,' the only answer is "as large as the largest unexplored geography."  Would be a good question, though.

Comment: After having long been thought to be extinct, one species of Coelacanth was disovered in 1938 and another was discovered in 1999. They can get to be two meters long and 90 kg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelacanth Someone who looks for such species in a less than scientific way is called a cryptozoologists and some cryptids sought included at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptids There is some evidence suggesting that may be a tribe or two of a hominin species similar to Homo Florensis on an Indonesian island. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orang_Pendek

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_squid).  I'm amazed it wasn't discovered until a few years ago.

Comment: Oceans might have a ton of hidden lifeforms, but there is also the possibility that there is life under the earth as well... and we know almost nothing about sub-terrain ecosystems. In addition, there is evidence of life forms that originally are assumed to be separate but are in reality a massive root network like: http://www.amusingplanet.com/2010/11/pando-single-largest-living-organism-on.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Land animal

First, the answer depends on your definition of 'undiscovered'. If you mean 'undiscovered to Western scientific classification' then it is quite possible that a currently known sub-species will be elevated to species sometime in the future; much like the African Elephant is in the process of being split into two species (the original bush elephant *Loxodonta africana* and the forest elephant *Loxodonta cyclotis* which a recent DNA analysis indicates is [more closely related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_forest_elephant) to an extinct European Elephant than to the bush elephant)

If you mean 'undiscovered by Westerners in general', the winner might be the [kting voar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kting_voar), if that is non-mythical and also non-extinct. The wikipedia page I linked is pretty skeptical, but consider that a different distinct bovid was found in the same region in 1992, the [saola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saola).

If you mean 'undiscovered by any people'; well, then it would have to be something Antarctic, or tiny, because people are everywhere. Its hard to even say what would constitute 'undiscovered' in that sense, so I'll let it pass.

## Aquatic animals

The first specimen of the [colossal squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_squid#Largest_known_specimen) was captured in 2007. Since it is only recently that the [giant squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_squid) and colossal squid were distinguished from each other, it is plausible that there could be another large squid type hanging out in the deeps (Titanic squid?)

Sleeper sharks are also large and poorly known. The [Southern Sleeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_sleeper_shark) Shark was determined to be distinct from the [Greenland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenland_shark) and [Pacific Sleeper Sharks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_sleeper_shark) only in 2004. The sleeper shark niche seems like a plausible place to find a new species. Another shark option are deepwater plankton feeding sharks like the [megamouth shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megamouth_shark). The megamouth has only been discovered in tropical regions; there could be a polar variant hiding in deep oceans.

## Trees

Given the incredible diversity of tree species in rainforests, I feel confident that there are 30m+ undiscovered trees hiding in the darkest Amazon or Papua New Guinea.

## Fungus

The [giant fungus in Orgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armillaria_ostoyae) was hardly suspected to exist until an [investigation in 2003](http://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/fsbdev3_033146.pdf). It seems pretty likely that such a fungus could exist elsewhere in the world without being noticed. A plausible location would be in the mountains of southern Siberia or Mongolia. They are sparsely populated and have a climate generally like that of Malheur National Forest in Oregon. Another option would be the lower Andes in Chile and Argentina.

Of course, looking for the same kind of giant fungus might blind us to the possibility of a different kind of giant fungus. Might there be huge fungal colonies collecting nutrients from rainwater washed underground from a lush rainforest? It could be in the [limestone caves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_Nha-K%E1%BA%BB_B%C3%A0ng_National_Park) under jungles of Vietnam, the [cenotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cenote) of the Yucatan, or even in the giant underground [counter-Amazon](http://www.livescience.com/15849-underground-river-discovered-beneath-amazon.html) ['river'](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-14693637).

Comment: This answer is currently closest to winning the bounty as it provides much of the information I need.  However it would be helpful to me if you could cite a source or calculate "at most as large as..." instead of giving examples - "at least as large as ..." Otherwise very thorough and much appreciated

Comment: I'd have added a section on eusocial insects. Are vast numbers of sterile worker castes individual animals, or part of a single colony that is the mature size of one instance of its species? If you accept the latter, then the supercolonies which arise when some new ant species is introduced to a new continent, might be of note.

Comment: You suggested fungal colonies, but may have neglected to mention the variously known, clonal colony ( i.e. physiologically conjoined? ) specimens. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonal_colony

Comment: This answer is closest to winning the bounty (ending tomorrow) but it will not receive it if it fails to say "at most this" as opposed to "at least this"

Comment: @Zxyrra It does say 'at most this'.

Comment: @kingledion I see several "at least as large as" but nothing says "it couldn't be larger than"

Comment: @zxyrra  To ask specifically for Must be of size x or smaller for something as vague as undiscovered is unreasonable simply because of one single factor, Population. Should the animal be nearly extinct and have a very small population, it could easily be the maximum size possible and go undiscovered simply because there are so few of them thanks to random chance. So your size limit is literally the maximum, except when you consider having more than a few of them. Other criteria you do not give are critical to answering this question to the precision requested

Comment: @Ryan Turn that into an answer in the next 49 minutes and the bounty is yours

Comment: There's really no upper limit on the size of an undiscovered fungus. There are certainly bacterial colonies miles underground. There could be an enormous fungal colony in the same environment. There's no reason there couldn't be a single enormous fungus a hundred miles across, threaded through the rocks two miles underground.

Answer (score 7):

There is an island in the Andaman Sea where the [human inhabitants literally kill on sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinelese_people) any human being that sets foot on the island. They are living a Stone Age tribal existence, but we don't know anything about their language and culture, because anyone who tried find out got dead before learning anything.

Whatever animal species exist on that island have been "discovered" and described only by those Stone Age natives.

Just about anything might be living there. As long as it can survive alongside a tribal human society - megafauna are probably out, for example. The archaeological records show that megafauna have never survived the arrival of human beings. But anything regular-sized (up to the size of an elephant) would be completely feasible.

If you want to know the theoretical maximum size this undiscovered land mammal could be, it will depend if you want it to be a mammal or not ([heat dissipation becomes an issue before biophysical weight/mass limits kick in](http://www.askabiologist.org.uk/answers/viewtopic.php?id=6836)), and whether it has live young or lays eggs. There is a [summary of research into size limits on sauropods](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-185X.2010.00137.x/full), which explains other factors like how much they chew their food and how long their necks are ...

The [contraints for sea animals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/317/is-there-a-maximum-size-an-ocean-bound-creature-could-grow-to) are admirably covered in the answers to this question.

I can't see any upper limit to the volume of a fungus, because [entire aspen forests are a single individual organism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)). The largest on record is 106 acres, and there would be no practical obstacle to it continuing to expand. Of course, if it couldn't live in sea water, your fungus would be constrained to the size of whatever land mass it was on, and, to remain undetected, would need to be under the surface of the ground, except for its "flowers" - whatever shaped thingy it pops up to spread its spores from time to time.

Comment: How are elephants not megafauna?

Comment: Well, @kingledon, anything over 40kg (88 pounds) could be defined as "megafauna", but that would be a pretty small elephant! The "mega" is relative to the "standard" and "miniature" versions of whatever species. I was referring to [Pleistocene megafauna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleistocene_megafauna). The elephant version of that is the woolly mammoth.

Comment: Tracking, but you said that humans make megafauna extinct, but elephants are feasible. It seems that if humans made megafauna extinct, than maybe monkey and rodents and other not-megafauna are more feasible.

Comment: @JnaniJennyHale saying that megafauna can't survive men while referring specifically to Pleistocene megafauna is circular logic. Obviously, no species extinct in Pleistocene is extant today - big or small. Saying that "mega" is relative to "standard" fauna is wrong too. Wolly mammoths were no bigger than modern African elephants, they are either both megafauna or none of them are.

Comment: The fossil records clearly show mass extinctions of megafauna in Australia, New Zealand, and the Americas, correlating with the arrival of human beings in the area. There are animals in Australia that weigh more than 40kg, but the megafauna kangaroos were much larger than the modern ones, even though some of the modern ones weigh more than 40kg. I think you are splitting hairs over terminology, because the point is clear. I you can think of a better word, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: @Jnani Jenny Hale: If the definition of 'megafauna' is only 40 kg, then in temperate North America the buffalo (300-1200 kg), moose (350-600 kg), elk (250-500 kg), and grizzly bear (130-360 kg) all easily qualify, and all exist in the wild.

Comment: @jamesqf, exactly my point. Modern "megafauna" like elephants would be conceivable on an island in the Andaman Sea but not the hyper-sized versions of modern-day animals that lived on continents without a human presence.

Comment: The bounty is about to expire but I do not have what I need to select any answer as of now. You may be able to win it if you address "at most this large" as opposed to "at least as large as"

Comment: Does that edit do it for you, @Zxyrra?

Comment: @JnaniJennyHale Once / if it addresses plants, fungi, and sea creatures yes (see bottom of question)

Comment: How about now, then? :)

Comment: You are now addressing everything but you do not explain the maximum size of undiscovered organisms in a quantative way - only the maximum size theoretically possible.

Comment: I am not sure what is the difference between "the maximum size theoretically possible" and "the maximum size". In the case of plants, it is limited only by your choice of land area. In the case of ocean creatures, it is limited only by the shape you want to make the creature (it can't be too bulky - you need a lot of surface area). In the case of land animals, it depends on whether you want a mammal, whether you want it to have live young, and how you want it to process its food. Unless you supply those details, an actual quantitative answer is not possible.

Comment: @kingledion The claim was that megafauna can't survive the _arrival_ of humans. Humans never arrived in Africa and Eurasia, they evolved in place alongside the animals, which is why the animals could slowly adapt to the slow evolution of humans and survive. Humans arrived in the rest of the world, and killled the megafauna, which had no time to adapt. Of course the Andaman Islands are in Asia, and so any megafauna there would have had time to adapt to humans.

Answer (score 3):

#### I believe that the calculations you are asking for are impossible.

One reason is the difficulty of defining discovery. Take [Bigfoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot). Has he been discovered? Plenty of people believe in him. Or does it only count if a reputable scientist bags one and carries it off to be stuffed in a museum of natural history?

And what about species that were only recently discovered to be *separate* species?

#### Empirical evidence provides a lower bound.

Every now and then, scientists [discover a new species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_megafauna_discovered_in_modern_times) or accept the descriptions by an indigenious people that were previously discounted.

- A new [monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar_snub-nosed_monkey) in 2010. Half a metre.
- A new [tapir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapirus_kabomani) in 2013. More than a metre.

From that we can [state with some confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) that an undiscovered, human-sized mammal might exist.

Comment: 1) "Discovered" is generally not "believing in", I mean discovered as "the body is found and identified as a separate species" or "it is observed multiple times and described" which is generally the way it is done in science - not "belief"

Comment: 2) If we're describing something drastically larger than what is thought to exist I doubt it will "recently be discovered to be separate (from something we know)"

Comment: If you accept "discovered to be separate species", then the size of a small elephant: http://www.birds.cornell.edu/brp/elephant/cyclotis/cyclotis.html  It's certainly possible that such a splitting of species could happen with whales, too.

Comment: >"Plenty of people believe in him." About as many as believe that all world leaders are lizards.

Comment: Another example. Giraffe have been found to be several distinct species. We thought they were only one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the [Soala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saola) meets your strict definitions, but it was discovered in 1992.

Also, [Mount Mabu](http://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2014-05-05/mount-mabu-mozambique-maphead-ken-jennings) is popularly known as the "Google Forest" because it was found via satellite mapping by a team looking for previously unexplored regions.  It's plausible that as-yet unknown species could live there.

TL;DR - it's totally plausible in my opinion.

Comment: The bounty is about to expire but I do not have what I need to select any answer as of now. You may be able to win it if you address "at most this large" as opposed to "yes things can be large" which is my question

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible to calculate a maximum sized organism (animal/plant/other) that could be still undiscovered, because it seems possible that an organism bigger than any that could possibly live might remain undiscovered.

For example, a hypothetical deep sea organism - plant, animal, or other - could grow to the size of a mountain - kilometers or miles in each dimension - and stick to the ocean floor.  Survey ships could pass over it with sonar scans and record it as an undersea mountain with unusual texture.  And who knows how long it might take for anyone to be interested enough to investigate more closely and discover it is a life form.

What about a giant sea monster that comes to the surface?  If it surfaces away from normal shipping lanes, it might never be seen or photographed.  There is no radar system that constantly scans the entire surface of the sea to detect ships, is there?  Are there satellite systems that constantly image the entire surface of the Earth and record it?  And if so, what is their resolution? How big would something have to be to certain to be detected?

I believe that under the right circumstances, organisms miles wide could come to the surface periodically and not be detected.  What about a sea creature that doesn't make songs, calls, echolocation and other vocal noises like whales do?  Could underwater hydrophones detect the sounds it make swimming if it was big enough?  And if so, how big would it have to be to certainly be detected?

Thus it seems possible, under the right circumstances, for plants, animals, and other organisms as big or bigger than any known to exist to remain undetected today.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I was amazed to learn that something larger than the Giant Squid, the [Colossal Squid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_squid) has been discovered.

Now the giant squid is found dead in fishing nets, but spotting a live one proved very difficult. I saw on TV one expidition thought it would be a good idea to go down in a bathesphere and just watch out the window—they *heard* whales in the area but didn’t see them, either.

The larger Colossal Squid was “spotted” in the stomoch of a whale in the early 20th century, but no intact specimen found until 2003.  If you had asked this question just a few years ago, would you beleive the answer would be 500–750 kg?

We *don’t* spot them in fishing nets or floating dead because of their habitat and lifestyle.  This suggests that very large and completely unknown animals may live at similar depths, and their physiology is such that they *sink* when they die.

The lifestyle causes it to be *large*.  These squid hang out below the deepest that normal fish can see, and using a *huge* eye watch for shadows against the glow from the surface. Then they need a huge *reach* to grab what they spotted.

So, another unrelated squid like that, or some other animal that makes its living in a similar way will tend to be very large.  Perhaps they have a slow metaboloism and eek out a living on rare dinner, but they never stop growing and live for hundreds of years.

How large could it possibly be, without us knowing about it already? I think it would be the *total biomass* limit, the size multiplied by the number of indivuals. If some unknown population was large enough to make a dent in the prey population, we would notice.

Comment: This is helpful information but (A) pertains to just aquatic animals when I also ask about plants, fungi, and land animals, and (B) does not address an actual size as I ask for in the question - see the "Edit" part of the question for more info.

Comment: So you want answers for all the categories separately? I thought you wanted possibilities among those categories.

Comment: I intended to have each answered separately but I will edit the question to make that more clear

Answer (score 0):

The Sentinelese are an indigenous population residing on an Island near India.

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinelese) they remain "virtually untouched and uncontested by modern civilization" and they have met near all attempts to make contact with violence.

The Indian government has heavily discouraged to attempt to access the Island they reside on or make contact. Perhaps you could work that into a story.

[The wiki page for "Uncontacted peoples" might interest you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontacted_peoples)